# How is std::allocator so fast?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, performance-testing, allocator

I believe it is not practical to access to implementation of Standard Library of C++ because it is platform-dependent (*correct me if this sentence was wrong!*). Well, I wanted practice about some very low level (at least, as low level as I can program in C++) things in C++. So, I started to write an Allocator class, just to practice, learn and if I create something useful I plan to use it in my real projects.
My class looks okay. It is as fast as classical `Base* pointer = new Derivative;` and `pointer->~Base(); ::operator delete[] (pointer);` allocation, construction, destruction and deallocation policy. In fact for 10000000 iterations my class is 0.1 second slower.
The reason I am asking this question is: std::allocator. For some it can be slow for specific reasons; but merely comparing with my implementation, **it is very fast**. Please observe my code:

```
int main()
{
    for(int x=0; x<10000000; x++)
    {
        /* TEST 1: Using my Allocator class
        A* a = Allocator<B>::construct(10,3.2);
        Allocator<A>::destruct(a);
        //*/

        /* TEST 2: Using operators 'new' and 'delete[]' 
        A* a = new B(10,3.2);
        delete a;
        //*/

        /* TEST 3: std::allocator
        std::allocator<B> allocator;
        std::allocator<A> deallocator;
        A* a = allocator.allocate(1);
        allocator.construct(a,10,3.2);
        deallocator.destroy(a);
        deallocator.deallocate(a,1);
        //*/
    }
}
```

**Additional important notes about my code:** class A is the base of class B. `Allocator<T>::construct(args...)` and `Allocator<T>::destruct(pointer)` are static inline methods. The first one both allocates memory (enough for **only one** object) and constructs object in this memory location (by using arguments). The second one first destructs objects then deallocates the memory location. All three tests result (as far as I debugged) exactly the same and work. I use this loop with those 3 seperate tests (one test for each time).

Here are the results for 10000000 iterations:
Test 1: app. 1.550 seconds
Test 2: app. 1.450 seconds
Test 3: app. 1.200 seconds
(Note: these numbers are approximate numbers)
Well, std::allocator is way faster than both. Maybe there isn't a huge distinction but I want to know the reason of this distinction. I am very curious about the implementation of std::allocator. Thank you for your help and time.

Additional information: I am using GCC 4.7.2 under Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal.

Comment: std::allocator is basically `new` and `delete` as far as I know.

Comment: @yngum: No. It's `::operator new()` and `::operator delete()`.

Comment: You should run each test in a different process and make sure you trash the core cache before each run, or else any successive test will run on a hot cache, reducing cache misses relative to the previous test. Also, how are you timing this test? What is the breakdown of user time and OS/system time?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by TEST 2, why not just `delete a;`?  Isn't it bad to mix `new[]`/`delete[]` with `new`/`delete`?

Comment: @Robert Kubrick, I do run each test in different process. Of course, I do not run each test in same loop. When I do test 1, I delete the comment of test 1 and run code. Same for others.

Comment: @ebyrob, I just wanted to use ::operator delete[]() because I wanted to manually destruct object by means of doing a->~A(); Do you think it affects performance?

Comment: Why wouldn't it affect performance?  What I don't get is how it works to `new` then `delete[]` at all.  I know there's a "normal" way to destruct a pointer before de-allocate, but I don't remember it off-hand.  (I seem to recall it affects object creation)

Comment: @ebyrob I edited my code. Now it is delete a; But run-time is the same. It still very slightly faster than my class but slower than std::allocator.

Comment: I notice this `allocator.destroy(a);` seems equivalent to: `a->~B();`.  Maybe try: `deallocator.destroy(a);`.

Comment: @ebyrob yeah just the same. std::allocator is still very fast. I hardly understood the purpose of the change (although I appreciate that it should be deallocator.destroy())

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to learn about branch prediction and CPU pipelining, low time-complexity algorithms for internal implementations, along with cache coherency in order to make something highly optimized. I don't know about `std::allocator`'s implementation, but judging from your question the things I've mentioned are areas to improve performance dramatically.

Edit: If `std::allocator` uses `new` and `delete` like the comments suggest, then it's quite easy to make a much more specific and optimized allocator with some memory pooling.

Answer (score 1):

The std:allocator will be reserving a pool of memory and doesn't need to do a system call every time you call construct on the other hand every time we do a new memory is allocated by system

Comment: Can you cite anything that supports this claim? How can `std::allocator` be stateless (as required by the standard) if it's working with a memory pool?

Comment: What aspect of stateless is stopping from acquiring the memory? if i take an example of a primitive type where there is no concept of new/delete. I  use a allocator to get an array 10 integer. 

std::allocator<int> a1;
int* a = a1.allocate(10);
a[9] = 7;
Which line do you think the memory is allocated?? @NicolasHolthaus